# Regex spaces restriction not matching

Tags: regex, spaces

I have the following regex: `^([^\s][a-zA-Z_\-]+\s)*([^\s][a-zA-Z_\-]+$)`

Does the following:

- no spaces at beggining
- no spaces at end
- no double spaces in between

However it doesn't match with these strings:

`abd d`

`a bdc`

It does match with these:

`abd de`

`ab cde`

So I think it's doing something else beside the points mentioned, I need for it to match with the abd d type of examples.

It should and does allow a single space in between, but as you can see only when the length of the string to the left and right of the single space is 2 or more.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `[^\s]` in the pattern that requires a non-whitespace char, it requires at least 2 chars in between string start/end and non-whtespace chunks inside the string. If you remove them, [your pattern will work](https://regex101.com/r/qRV4p7/1).

However, I'd recommend to remove unnecessary `\` before `-` (at the end of the character class, escaping `-` is not required) and quantify the *last* part, closer to the end, this way, it will require less backtracking:

```
^[a-zA-Z_-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z_-]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oeALNi/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `_` or `-`
- `(?:\s[a-zA-Z_-]+)*` - 0+ occurrences of:

  - `\s` - a whitespace char
  - `[a-zA-Z_-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred way I do it.
Is never prone to backtracking problems.

This is the faster way if you have a lot of single letter's separated by spaces.

`^[a-zA-Z_-](?:\s?[a-zA-Z_-])*$`

https://regex101.com/r/dRpDYE/1

Formatted

```
 ^                     # BOS
 [a-zA-Z_-]            # Single a-z, etc..
 (?:                   # Cluster 
      \s?                   # Optional space, the only place a space can match
      [a-zA-Z_-]            # Must be followed by single a-z, etc..
 )*                    # End cluster, do 0 to many times 
 $                     # EOS
```